# Quitting in probation period

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period, probation

I am currently in a probation period at work. I want to quit as it’s harming my mental health. I have to provide 3 months notice if I hand in my notice during the probation period. However they can dismiss me at any time during my probation period.

I want to work the 3 months as it will
motivate me and give me the time to apply for other jobs, but wondering if once I hand in my notice if they can reduce my notice period to a month?

Comment: please specify your country, it can make a big difference in the rules. Have you reviewed all the documents? Normally during a probationary period the required notice is very short.

Comment: One person being able to fire at will while other must give notice is not going to be binding in some places, so knowing location is important. But also if you are not ready to leave (not having another job lined up), why do you want to tell them anything? WIth most probation you can just say at the end of term "No, thank you" and leave.

Comment: I’m in the UK. I did double check with HR and yes they’ve said three months notice is required. I want the three months to work but I also need the weight off my shoulder of knowing I don’t have to stay there much longer so I want to hand in my notice now but obviously not if they can change that to a month as I’m still in a probation period.

Comment: If they can already dismiss you at any time then it seems like the answer is yes?

Comment: Get your doctor to sign you off re mental health. Then if they try to dismiss you once they have the doctor's note that might be grounds for unfair dismissal...

Comment: You may want to read https://www.safeworkers.co.uk/employment-law/employment-probation-periods-what-you-need-know/

Comment: From MarkRotteveel link, your notice seems to be 1 week rather than 3 month during your probation period

Comment: I just posted a question on law.stackexchange.com whether this is legal at all or not.

Comment: @Worker86 HR may say 3 months but, does your contract say 3 months as well? (just to be completely clear you should check it)

Answer (score 3):

I think you answered yourself:

> [...] wondering if once I hand in my notice if they can reduce my notice period to a month?

But before that you mention (emphasis mine):

> I have to provide 3 months notice if I hand in my notice during the probation period. **However they can dismiss me at any time during my probation period**.

Based on this information the answer is **yes, they can dismiss you earlier if they want to**.

Generally speaking, this is one of the goals of having a probation period. So both you and your employer see if things are working out and if it's worth to move on to a more permanent position.

It's a bit odd (at least to me) that they ask for a 3 month notice when on your probation... personally I think it's a bit long for a notice period (the "usual" time is 2 week notice). I assume that the probation period is a multiple of 3 (6, 9, 12 months) and thus why they ask for 3... still, pondering about this has no practical purpose/benefit for you (just a comment mostly).

Comment: I'm not that familiar with UK law, but in NL, the notice period for an employee must always be equal to **or shorter than** the notice period for the employer, and I would expect the UK to have similar rules. And according to https://www.safeworkers.co.uk/employment-law/employment-probation-periods-what-you-need-know/ for the UK, if there is no explicit notice period specified for the probation period, it is one week, or none at all in the first month.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the link. OP mentioned 3 months, suggesting that's what is specified in their probation agreement/contract, so OP can't "just" give one week and go without burning bridges... On another note, I fail to see how the fact that employee period <= employer period for NL has something to do here...

Comment: Because _"I would expect the UK to have similar rules"_

Comment: Or no, the OP may just not be able to read the contract. It may have a 3 months' notice period AFTER the probation and rely on the counterparty knowing the regulations during the probation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain that this type of notice is valid in the UK. It does seem unbalanced, but this isn't /law. Feel free to ask there, or contact any of the law-assistance charities in the UK.

> I want to work the three months as it will motivate me and give me the time to apply for other jobs, but I'm wondering if, once I hand in my notice, they can reduce my notice period to a month?

That certainly can happen. Ultimately, they've learned all they need to know - that it won't work out - and, if there's no reason to keep you (it usually isn't worth keeping someone like that onboard), they can terminate you at any time.

Cold? Yes, but that's the contract you've signed.

> I want the three months, but I also need the weight off my shoulder, knowing I don’t have to stay there much longer.

Then you probably will have to burn a bridge, at least a little.

This means you should keep your plans quiet, go job hunting, and once you have a new job lined up with a start date agreed upon, a contract signed - the works - then, and only then, should you provide notice at your current job, and only up to your new starting date.

Yes, technically, you will be in breach, but realistically there's no recourse for it, especially not in your situation. It is what some may call something from the dictionary of the bird people, and it definitely is not going to win you many friends, but that's the situation they've created by writing the contract the way they did.

Of course, you could instead gamble and hope for understanding from your current boss and hope he will give - and then keep - a handshake agreement. But, honestly, the risk vs reward is just not worth it, compared to maybe a few memories with very few people. At least in my view that is; if this is some very tight-knit circle where word travels fast, you may be out of luck and just have to gamble on them not cancelling your notice period.

Either way, the lesson is that the next time someone offers you a contract like this, consider negotiating more balanced terms. They may tell you all about the "standard contract" and other empty promises, but honestly, not being willing to give you any job security, while keeping all the security for themselves, is a pretty obvious warning flag.

Answer (score 1):

If your mental health is really suffering, then the best advice would be just to find another job and then terminate your current contract on the spot without notice, on the grounds of ill health being caused by the employment, and the ensuing frustration of the contract.

When an employer seeks to impose a 3 month notice period on you (which is a really extreme notice period, especially for a new starter in a business), but offers only a month's notice in return, it says everything about that employer. It says to me this is a bottom-feeding employer, who sweat their workforce and lose people all the time, and this is their latest gambit to try and stem the turnover.

Their most likely response is to simply accept that you've left without any fuss.

If they really wanted people to respect the notice period, then they could have agreed to give equal notice themselves, rather than imposing a situation upon you where you have to give an extremely long notice period, but then risk being dismissed much sooner. My opinion on this is to fight fire with fire and be equally unreasonable in your own favour.

You will of course lose any prospect of a reference, but for an employment lasting just a couple of months, few are ever going to care.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on what country you are in. Just because its in the agreement, doesn't make it legal.  What can they do if you just leave?

- They can not give you a reference (again that would be illegal in NZ).
- They can take you to court, which is unlikely.

As an employer, I have always felt that the law favoured the employee.  Realistically, they could just walk off whenever they wanted to, but I couldnt fire them on the spot.

I would get some legal advice.